# Postgres select by prefix within certain period then sort it .. slow performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I want to select records that have geohash (a string) begins with `b` within a certain period and order the results by num of pics, but it is slow.

Table:

```
create table test (
    geohash varchar(20),
    num_pics integer,
    dt date,
    body varchar(1000)
)
```

Dummy data (run 5 times to insert 10m records)

```
insert into test 
select g, v, d, b from (
    select generate_series(1, 2000000) as id, 
    left(md5(random()::text),9) as g, 
    floor(random() * 100000 + 1)::int as v, 
    timestamp '2014-01-10 20:00:00' + random() * (timestamp '2020-01-20 20:00:00' - timestamp '2014-01-10 10:00:00') as d,
    md5(random()::text) as b) a
```

Plus 1m data with `geohash` start with `b`

```
insert into test 
select g, v, d, b from (
    select generate_series(1, 1000000) as id, 
    'b' || left(md5(random()::text),9) as g, 
    floor(random() * 100000 + 1)::int as v, 
    timestamp '2014-01-10 20:00:00' + random() * (timestamp '2020-01-20 20:00:00' - timestamp '2014-01-10 10:00:00') as d,
    md5(random()::text) as b) a
```

Index

```
create index idx on test(geohash, dt desc , num_pics desc)
```

My query

```
explain analyze 
  select * 
  from test 
  where geohash like 'b%' 
    and dt between timestamp '2014-02-21 00:00:00' 
               and timestamp '2014-02-22 00:00:00' 
  order by num_pics desc limit 1000
```

Query Plan (https://explain.depesz.com/s/XNZ)

```
'Limit  (cost=75956.07..75958.10 rows=814 width=51) (actual time=1743.841..1744.141 rows=1000 loops=1)'
'  ->  Sort  (cost=75956.07..75958.10 rows=814 width=51) (actual time=1743.839..1744.019 rows=1000 loops=1)'
'        Sort Key: num_pics DESC'
'        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 254kB'
'        ->  Index Scan using idx on test  (cost=0.56..75916.71 rows=814 width=51) (actual time=2.943..1741.071 rows=1464 loops=1)'
'              Index Cond: (((geohash)::text >= 'b'::text) AND ((geohash)::text < 'c'::text) AND (dt >= '2014-02-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (dt <= '2014-02-22 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))'
'              Filter: ((geohash)::text ~~ 'b%'::text)'
'Planning time: 279.249 ms'
'Execution time: 1744.194 ms'
```

**Question**:

Seems like it is hitting the index but still the performance is slow. Is it the problem of `Filter: 'b%'`? If it was translated into `geohash >= 'b' and geohash <'c'` in the optimizer, then why it has to filter it again?

Also, is it a correct way to use a multi column B tree index? Because I read that it is the best to use `equality(=)` operator in the first indexed column, instead of a `range` operator in this case.

Comment: `Planning time: 279.249 ms` is rather high, too. Do you have some kind of network-disk?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess since I haven't tested it. The query "access" is being done by the wrong column.

Rule of thumb:

1. **Access** by the most selective column.
2. **Filter** using the less selective column.

In this case `geohash` is not very selective since the pattern only has one letter. If it had more than that -- say 3 or more letters -- then it would be more selective. The selectivity is: one letter out of 26 (maybe only 16?) is `1 / 26 = 3.84%`. Rather bad.

It seems that `dt` is more selective in this case, since it covers a single day (out of 2000 days?). The selectivity is: `1 / 2000 = 0.05%`. Much better.

Try the following index, to see if you get faster execution time:

```
create index idx2 on test(dt, geohash, num_pics);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to ask after first sign it is better to create index for this not general index;

```
 create index on test using btree(substr(geohash,1,1)); 
 create index on test using btree(dt desc); analyze test;

  explain analyze 
  select 
  from test 
  where substr(geohash,1,1) ='b' 
    and dt between timestamp '2014-02-21 00:00:00' and timestamp '2014-02-22 00:00:00' 
  order by num_pics desc limit 1000
```

Execution plan

```
 Limit  (cost=15057.49..15059.14 rows=660 width=4) (actual time=29.433..29.644 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=15057.49..15059.14 rows=660 width=4) (actual time=29.431..29.564 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: num_pics DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 117kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=96.93..15026.58 rows=660 width=4) (actual time=10.782..28.708 rows=1469 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((dt >= '2014-02-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (dt <= '2014-02-22 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
              Filter: (substr((geohash)::text, 1, 1) = 'b'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 8470
              Heap Blocks: exact=9481
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_dt_idx  (cost=0.00..96.77 rows=4433 width=0) (actual time=5.541..5.541 rows=9939 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((dt >= '2014-02-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (dt <= '2014-02-22 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning time: 0.325 ms
Execution time: 30.065 ms
```

With the composite index, it is even better

```
create index on test using btree(substr(geohash,1,1), dt desc); 

Limit  (cost=2546.25..2547.90 rows=660 width=51) (actual time=6.188..6.679 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2546.25..2547.90 rows=660 width=51) (actual time=6.186..6.528 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: num_pics DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 255kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=16.85..2515.34 rows=660 width=51) (actual time=1.896..4.740 rows=1469 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((substr((geohash)::text, 1, 1) = 'b'::text) AND (dt >= '2014-02-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (dt <= '2014-02-22 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
              Heap Blocks: exact=1430
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_substr_dt_idx  (cost=0.00..16.68 rows=660 width=0) (actual time=1.266..1.266 rows=1469 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((substr((geohash)::text, 1, 1) = 'b'::text) AND (dt >= '2014-02-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (dt <= '2014-02-22 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning time: 0.389 ms
Execution time: 7.052 ms
```